# rails: User close tab in the middle of an AJAX call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I was wondering what happens to an AJAX call if the user close the tab or navigate away after the call is being sent.

Will the AJAX call still being processed or will it stop because there's no session? If it's will be stopped, is there a `ignore_user_abort` equivalent in RoR like there is in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?

One the user closes the tab or navigates away, browser will drop the call. However Rails will still process the query. It will just drop the output because session is gone.

You can give this a try by calling:

```
def index
   puts "start"
   sleep 5
   puts "end"
end
```

If you monitor your logs, you'll see that request will start and end, even if user leaves

Comment: I am counting on some logic being done on that call (update the db with a few calls from my Rails backend to another service).
I just want to make sure that the call won't be dropped by rails if the user decides to close the tab after the ajax call has been sent.